# Is this reservoir for power steering fluid? (1989 Fleetwood Southwind Motorhome)

Tags: power-steering, part-identification, rv

Low-speed steering on this RV causes a loud squeal, presumably a slipping belt. I am trying to find check the level of the power steering fluid. I found this unmarked reservoir in the forward compartment (in front of the engine).

(click for full size)
[image]

The cap doesn't help much:

[image]

I have tried to follow the tube coming out of the bottom of the reservoir, and it looks promising, but I'm not certain (it's difficult to trace). I haven't identified a reservoir for the brakes yet, either, so it could be that.

**EDIT:** I tried again to trace the line coming out of the reservoir. It goes to something that is turned by the motor (presumably the hydraulic pump). From there a line goes to the brake master cylinder, then the steering gear, then back to the pump. This matches what the chassis owner's manual says:

[image]

This cap/dipstick drawing looks very similar to the actual cap/dipstick in the reservoir.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes that is the power steering reservoir.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is your PS Fluid reservoir. Brake Fluid Reservoirs do not have the dipstick type of cap you have displayed!